# How to display data from one object in JTextArea of another object?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I have one class named handler and this class process the http request comming from the browser and i want to display the http headers of the request in JTextArea of another class named HttpHeadersFrame! This is what i have tried

```
 public class Handler
 {
     HttpHeadersFrame headersFrame; //This frame contains JTextArea component
     private Request request = null;
     public String requestMessage;
     private Socket socket = null;

     public Handler(Socket socket)
     {
         this.socket = socket;
         this.headersFrame = new HttpHeadersFrame();
         headersFrame.setVisible(true);
     }

     public void processRequest()
     {
        requestMessage = request.toString(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        headersFrame.getRequestTextArea().append(requestMessage);
     }
 }
```

When i run the proxy i don't get any message in JTextArea! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can't see something about proxy, eeeerrrrrhrttt are you have got issues with loading data behind proxy server....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is lack of proper usage of Swing components in your snippet.
You should initialize the `requestTextArea` field in constructor before using it.
And also you have to add it to frame with a statement

```
this.getContentPane().add(requestTextArea);
```

You should pass `HttpHeadersFrame` instance to your Handler class, make this instance visible, i.e.

```
headersFrame = new HttpHeadersFrame();
headersFrame.setVisible();
```

And appending `requestMessage` to this instance's textArea field will work.

Comment: It works-the messages are being displayed in JTextArea but so many headerFrames pop up when i try to run the proxy! How to fix the issue?

Comment: You are creating a new HttpHeadersFrame() instance with every call of processRequest() method. Remove that line and initialize it in the constructor of Handler class. OK?

Comment: I did it! Sorry i had forgotten to to modify codes in the post message! Many httpHeadersFrames are still popping up!

Comment: So you have a lot of Handler objects? Each of them having its own JFrame (HttpHeadersFrame). Make the frame final static so that all the objects share the same frame instance. OK?

Comment: Cheers dude! No many frames anymore! Thanx a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your `processRequest` method you create a new `HttpHeadersFrame` on each incoming request. Unless you display all those frames, you will constantly updating a non-visible frame instead of the one-and-only visible one. So pass a visible `HttpHeadersFrame` instance to your `Handler` class iso creating new instances and your problem will be solved.

Oh, and please make sure you update the Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: What do you mean pass a visible HttpHeadersFrame instance to your Handler class ? Would plz you post an example? Thanx

Comment: You say you do not see any message. You should pass the reference to that visible `HttpHeadersFrame` to your handler, iso creating a new one in your handler each time you process a request

Comment: It works-the messages are being displayed in JTextArea but so many headerFrames pop up when i try to run the proxy! How to fix the issue?